# Can you export Session Quality score to BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

My data qualifies for a Session Quality score and I see this information in my GA account. My GA data is passed to BigQuery daily, but I don't have Session Quality score in here - is it possible to add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to export Session Quality or Average Session Quality metrics to Google BigQuery, however this feature will available in the future.